# How to properly call a function within itself?

Tags: python, function, recursion, return-value

I should call the `myfunction` from `myfunction` when request is failed due to authorization problem. See the code below.

```
def myfunction(parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4=None):
    error_text = None
    result = None

    response, error_code = do_some_external_call()
    if error_code == 401: # auth_error
        login()
        result, error_text = myfunction(parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4)
        return result, error_text # ???
    if response:
        result = response.result
    return result, error_text
```

Should I return `result, error_text` at the line marked with `???`? Or would it be enough just to call `return`?

Comment: *"would it be enough just to call `return`?"* - did you try it? What happened?

Comment: Maybe we are missing code here but none of your parameter are assigned beforehand, also what is your goal ? your question seems vague to me.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes, I tried and had some problems, but not sure if they were related to this particular line. In result I've decided to learn how it works.

Comment: @scharette, what do you mean by 'none of your parameter are assigned beforehand'? Which parameter is not assigned?

Comment: Well, how do you expect `result, error_text = myfunction(...)` to work if it has paths that *don't* return a sequence of two things? You could just `return myfunction(...)`, then you don't have to worry specifically about how what gets returned. It's not clear to me what you mean by *"how it works"* - what do you think the bare `return` would do?

Comment: see above answer and what I meant was I just don't see why these parameters even exists, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it should return either `None, 'some error text'` or `'Some good result', None`. Do you think this is incorrect behaviour?

Comment: Returning `success, error` is certainly not pythonic, as a rule. If there's an error, *throw an error*. But that doesn't seem related to the question you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use recursion when you can use a simple loop.

```
def myfunction(parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4=None):
    while True:
        response, error_code = do_some_external_call()
        if error_code == 401:
            login()
        else:
            break        
    return getattr(response, 'result', None), error_code
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fine just to return the function directly, you can test this easily enough in the REPL. This is the quickest example that I could think of:

```
def reccy3(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return x, 1
    return reccy3(x-1)
```

For your code, you don't appear to set `error_text` anywhere, so I'm going to assume you mean `error_code`. You can easily modify the below to include `error_text` however you're using that.

```
def myfunction(parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4=None):
    response, error_code = do_some_external_call()
    if error_code == 401: # auth_error
        login()
        return myfunction(parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4)
    if response:
        return response.result, None
    return None, error_code
```

Answer (score -3):

You should tyr to reqeite this function so it have only a single return - it will be easier to understand. Other than that, of course, all return statements have to respect the function signature returning two objects. Why would it be different?